# Landscape orientation in Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get an app to display in landscape orientation. For that I am adding:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

to my config.xml file.
The problem I have is that it sets the application to be always in one landscape orientation. That is, "landscape" works, but "upside-down landscape" doesn't. 
I would expect to have Phonegap writing "sensorLandscape" in the Android manifest, but it writes "landscape" instead. 
I don't seem to be able to modify the manifest by hand either since Phonegap recreates the file in the next build, or to [use config.xml to overrride the manifest file, as Phonegap **Build** allows](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/), since I am building the app locally.

Comment: It writes whatever you put into the `value`, so if you put `value="landscape"` it will be `landscape`. Try `<preference name="orientation" value="sensorLandscape" />`

Comment: yup, tried that, it replies (to: cordova run android)

Unsupported global orientation: sensorLandscape
Defaulting to value: default

Comment: I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Cordova. You can try the following options:

1. You can use this plugin. It's very easy to use: https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation/
2. As you said you can override manifest file using PhoneGap. I don't see any problem in installing a local PhoneGap CMD and building the app. Maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: A plug-in is definitely a possible solution. I am using Phonegap locally (it seems like these override options are only valid for the "build" version of Phonegap but I modifying the manifesto doesn't cut it, because it gets recreated every time.